# Overlaying <div> on another (dynamically positioned) <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3deqka/)**

I know SO has well over few dozen questions that ask something similar to what I stated in the title but my challenge is somewhat unique as I'll explain below. I have a set of `div` blocks arranged as follows:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='left-pane'>Left pane</div>
    <div id='right-pane'>
        <div id='right-top-content'>Right top</div>
        <div id='right-bottom-content'>Right bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id='showlayer'>Add layer</button>
<div id='orphan'>Boo...I'm a blue layer!</div>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to overlay a layer (another `div` block) right on top of the `div#right-pane` so that the areas labeled as "Right top" (light blue) and "Right bottom" (green) get completely covered. The resulting layout will look like the following:

[image]

Seems pretty straightforward but there are a couple of caveats. First, both `div` elements in the `#right-pane` should remain in place (i.e., should stay only hidden under the overlaid div); meaning the following approach doesn't do me any good:

```
$("#right-pane").empty().append($("#orphan"));
```

Second, the width of the "Left pane" will dynamically change, so the positioning of the overlay div will need to be dynamically adjusted as well (I think). As you can see in my jsFiddle demo (see above), the overlay div has 'absolute' positioning along with a z-index value, which seems to be the most common approach for overlaying an element. This sort of works but both the "top" and "left" values can/will change.

So, what's the best way to tackle this challenge? I might be able to just calculate the "left" and "top" position of the overlay div if I have to, but is there a more elegant way of accomplishing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple.  You need to also use `position: relative`.  Add it to `#right-pane` and then make `#orphan` a child of `#right-pane`.

How absolute positioning works is the `top` and `left` attributes correlate to the top and left corner of the first non-static parent.  That would be `#right-pane` because we gave it `position:relative`.  Relative positioning doesn't effect flow or change the rendered position unless you add `top`, `left`, etc. to it, so our parent isn't effected.  We have to change it to `relative` (or `absolute` or `fixed`) because the default is `position:static`.  Hopefully that all makes sense.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/61bsptrj/1)

```
#right-pane {
    width:300px;
    float:left;

    position: relative;
}
```

Edit:  I also changed the `#orphan` style rule to use percent based width and height.  You can do that because of the absolute positioning with the relative parent.  Both `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` and `width` and `height` become relative to the parent.

```
#orphan {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; /* changed width and height to be dynamic */
    display:none;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery like this:

```
$("#showlayer").click(function () {

    $("#orphan").css({
        'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'block',
            'z-index': '10',
            'top': 0,
            'right': 0
    });

    /* This solution seems to work but not quite!
    $("#orphan").css({
        'float': 'left',
        'display': 'inline'
    });
    $("#right-pane")
        .empty()
        .append($("#orphan"));
    */
});
```

and then move the #orphan div and make some tiny changes in your CSS, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c4zhbve/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
display: table-cell; /*(IE8+) for the columns*/
display: table; /*for the wrapper*/
```

your divs will works like a TABLE adapting size automatically only with css.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5u3deqka/5/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `offset` method to get the `top` and `left` of `#right-pane`:

```
$("#orphan").css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'display': 'block',
    'z-index': '10',
    'top': $('#right-pane').offset().top,
    'left': $('#right-pane').offset().left
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3deqka/2/)**